# Ajax Validation on JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I want to validate required fields on diferent forms when i push on *save* (Toolbar.xhtml). How can i do this? Thanks in advance

I have the following code:

`Father.xhtml`

```
..
<ui:include src="/jsf/Toolbar.xhtml"/>
<ui:include src="/jsf/Adquisicion.xhtml"/>
..
```

`Toolbar.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      >

 <ui:insert name="toolbarComponent">
  <h:form name="ToolbarForm" >
    <a4j:commandLink id="save" action="#{backingBean1.save}"/>
  </h:form>
 </ui:insert>

</ui:composition>
```

`Adquisicion.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

 <ui:insert name="component">
   <a4j:form id="Adquisicion">
     <rich:panel>
       <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="Header" />
       </f:facet>
       <h:panelGrid columns="3">
  <h:outputText value="Name" />
  <h:inputText id="nameId" value="#{adquisicion.name}"                 style="width:500px;" required="true" requiredMessage="Required" >
            <a4j:support event="onblur"/>
         </h:inputText>
  <rich:message for="nameId" style="color: red;"/>
     </rich:panel>
   <a4j:form> 
 </ui:insert>
<ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input fields have to go in the **same** `<h:form>` (or `<a4j:form>`, whatever you like) as the command link/button.